# Сохранение bitmap'a в файл не работает

Tags: android

Есть код:

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Android/data/ru.vspr/data/sct.jpg");
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos)
        } catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Почему не создаются папка и файль(по-умолчанию они отсутствуют)? Всё работает, если выбрать /sdcard/ в качестве пути. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: ПОтому что папки должны существовать. создайте весь путь сначала кроме файлов.

Comment: Как создать путь? Надеюсь не вручную

Comment: гугл вам в помощь

Comment: `File.mkdirs()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохранение изображения в файл:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "name.jpg");
    mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("SuperCreeper", e.toString());
}
```

Не забыть в манифесте поставить разрешение записи на SD карту.